# Two editor’s notes within a footnote

Tags: footnotes

Is the use of an asterisk and a dagger workable in the following quote which is supplied with a footnote and needs two embedded notes by the editor? (the quotation is much longer so in fact less cluttered than it appears below)

‘The [intellect]* is first of all merely a faculty of the [hu]man-person [podobnie jak właśiwością jego jest wolność].†’

FOOTNOTE: Wojtyła, The Acting Person, 158. [* ‘Mind’ in the English translation, however, ‘umysł’ is used in the original. † Omitted in the English translation but present in the Polish original—Ed.]

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not really a question about the language, but about what orthography your publication will accept, and there is no single right answer there. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question on orthographic conventions. As choster says, different authorities (bosses / editors / tutors) will have different 'rules'.